# Disk2vhd Hyper-V server question

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, vhd

Hello all I have a backed up about 30 servers using disk2vhd and now I have built my first of many hyper-v severs I did not realize this is all command line I did download CoreConfigurator and that does have some functionality I have been looking for. My question is how do I get the VHD files to run a Vitual Machines? its all command line I tried via vbs to mount the VHD's and I have not been able to any help on this would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using servercore, You maybe can do everything from the command line but I always prefer to have one computer running a Non server core version of windows 2008 to be the management server.  You will load up Hyper-V manager on the non server core box and manage your Hyper-V server.

To have no "management" servers or desktops on your network will be a big pain IMO for management.

Using Hyper-V Manager you can quickly load the VHD's as VM's.

So load up Hyper-V Manager on a desktop PC on your localnet, and use its connect option to connect to your servercore.  (Make sure your firewall settings are ok on servercore using coreconfig)